# Showing $\tan x$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,\pi/4]$

Tags: uniform-continuity

Since any function which is continuous on a closed and bounded interval is uniformly continuous, in that way the given function is uniformly continuous.

And in the $\epsilon, \delta$ method I tried this much. For $x,y\in[0,\pi/4]$ $|x-y|\leq \pi/4(=\delta) \implies|f(x)-f(y)|=|\tan x-\tan y|=|\frac{\sin(x-y)}{\cos x.\cos y}|\leq 1=\epsilon$ Then choosing $\delta=\pi\epsilon/4$ , we have uniformly contnuity of the function. Should I do anything more?

Comment: No, you can't just choose $\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: @T.Bongers  explain why

Comment: Because the definition of (uniform) continuity is of the form "for all $\epsilon$", not for some.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct, since it relies on the choice $\epsilon = 1$; you need to be much more precise with the estimates. Starting at your end,

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\sin{(x - y)}}{\cos x \cos y}\right| &\le \frac{|x - y|}{\left(\cos \pi/4\right)^2}
\end{align*}

where we have used that $|\sin(z)| \le |z|$ and that cosine is decreasing on $[0, \pi/4]$. This should give the choice of $\delta$, as well as show you why $\tan$ is not uniformly continuous on, say, $[0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: you mean I had to assume $\delta= \epsilon/2$ ?

Comment: Sure, that choice of $\delta$ works.

Comment: thanks a lot but what should I do if $x\in [0,\pi/2)$

Comment: Well, what would the replacement of $\cos \pi/4$ be? Why would that be a problem?

Comment: you mean I have to take same for this also?

Comment: Spend a few minutes thinking about why this proof does not work if $\pi/4$ is replaced by $\pi/2$ (although this really wasn't part of your original question, just an aside).